# Why does Angular provide ng-maxlength when there is a standard maxlength?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, flawed-concept

HTML [provides](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) a standard maxlength attribute since version 4.01.
Angular provides a [ng-maxlength](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) directive.

The difference is that the standard approach doesn't allow entering more than max, while Angular's approach just generates a validation error.

Why did they decide to include such a directive? It's not because of dynamic data binding of maxlength since the behaviour is inconsistent. It's not because of compatibility since it's available even in HTML 4.01. My only guess is that it's there to provide an alternative validation paradigm, but it sounds like over-engineering.

Comment: As you said - `maxlength` defines the property of an HTML element. `ng-maxlength` defines how to validate a model. Maybe it's over-engineered, maybe not. I guess it is pretty arbitrary.

Comment: The same thing you could ask, why to use `ng-validate` to check if something is a number, or just use `<input type="number">` (forget the compatibility issues for a while)

Comment: IHMO, I think it's mainly because of the form management of Angular : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form > ngMaxLength is binded to validation / error events (and related CSS classes), when HTML attribute is not.

Comment: @BarthZalewski - fair point: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/262659/which-user-input-validation-approach-is-better-preventing-or-explaining

Comment: That's a good one, @Den

Comment: Does that really need a flawed-concept tag?...

Comment: @zneak it's the best companion tag for HTML, JavaScript and JS frameworks.

Comment: @den see my answer below. Consider updating the accepted answer for the sake of new visitors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not only it provide validation for max length, it also adds a class `ng-invalid-maxlength`.
so when you put anything beyond the limit `ng-invalid-maxlength` class will placed there
and in that class you can write your own css.

So after key press if validation fails, the css will be invoked simultaneously and reflects on your UI.

Comment: "This directive is also added when the plain maxlength attribute is used"... so this answer is longer correct.

Answer (score 17):

The previous answer may of been correct in earlier versions of angular but as of today and Angular v1.5.5, it looks like `maxlength` does exactly the same thing as `ng-maxlength` but also enforces the HTML inputs maxlength property on inputs of type text.

**Example:**

```
<input type="text" maxlength=5>
```

`maxlength` will enforce a 5 character max on the input and also add the correct angular validation class to the input.

Whereas `ngMaxlength` will only enforce validation. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength

**Advise:**
Just use `maxlength`.