# we should use ng-maxlength or maxlength in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am building an application with angularJS, we have to give max length validation in it.

so we should use ng-maxlength or html maxlength attribute ?

what difference will it make?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907669/why-does-angular-provide-ng-maxlength-when-there-is-a-standard-maxlength

Comment: thanks. It clarifies the doubt.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you like to strict length of an input field use `maxlength`.
- If you like to validate the field value on its length use
  `ng-maxlength`. If a user inputs more than `ng-maxlength` attribute
  value then `ng-invalid-maxlength` class will be set to the field.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the standard approach(html) doesn't allow entering more than max, while Angular's(angular JS) approach just generates a validation error.