# Limit length of number entered in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
<input class="span10" type="number" max="99999" ng-maxLength="5" placeholder="Enter Points" ng-change="myFunc($index)" ng-model="myVar">
```

This will only change the value of `form.input.$valid` to `false` if value is larger than 99999 or 5 digits. otherwise its `true`. However , the user is still able to enter any length number. **I just want to limit the digits he is entering just like maxlength of html.**

Comment: use regex for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use the maxlength attribute as well.  This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907669/why-does-angular-provide-ng-maxlength-when-there-is-a-standard-maxlength) explains why.

***Edit***
Seems Chrome is not honoring the maxlength when the input type is number, but it does for input type of text.  Edge and IE do honor the maxlength when the input type is number.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome) for info on that.

Comment: dosen't seems to be working. Only setting valid to false. Still be able to enter more than 5 digits.